# Simple way to achieve constant output current from a boost converter for battery charging in an EV penetration simulation study using EMTP simulation

Tags: battery-charging, charging, constant-current, power-engineering, electric-vehicle

I am simulating Level 1 and Level 2 EV chargers to test the impact of such chargers on a grid in a developing country. I am simulating in [EMTP-RV](https://emtp.com/) (software for simulation and analysis of power systems), and as the models of the battery (lithium-ion) and feeder are detailed, I need a simple method to control the current at the output (in order to realize the first few seconds of constant current charging). The reason is that the memory of EMTP-RV is almost fully used when I try to run the simulation with the grid and battery model. I have tried both current and voltage mode control as given by "Pulse Width Modulated DC-to-DC Power Conversion: Circuits, Dynamics, and Control Designs by Byungcho Choi".

However, this is too complex for my application, and unfortunately, I don't have the luxury of time to troubleshoot my design. Please note that I just need to observe the transients that occur when the chargers are placed on the grid, i.e., when they begin charging the batteries (*I have a simple current limiter to limit the inrush current on startup). I am currently trying a simple comparator with a current-sensing resistor, but I am making no headway as of yet. I will appreciate any assistance or guidance anyone can offer at this time.

Comment: Any schematics, diagrams, pictures, more specific details?

Comment: My apologies, I can provide some screenshots, block diagrams and spice files. Do give me a moment to consolidate.

Comment: Here is a link to a document with the requested information. The block diagram in Figure 7 should work, but the tuning is the issue. Here is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qiHDdjh9-_3OSUsRQs6teSAOlCPnAwaf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: From what I can see, your current output has too much ripple/spikes to be useful for proper PWM control. You should add an output filter with an inductor and a capacitor to significantly reduce the ripple. You may also add a small RC filter at the input of your comparator, although it will affect its speed.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your suggestion, I will try that.